# Faster query filter for getting a document with "greatest" field value?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, aggregation

In an Elasticsearch index I have document having fields: `fooId` and `fooField`.

I would like to fetch the document with a given `fooId` value but the largest value of `fooField`. Right now, I have a filtered query with an aggregation like this one:

```
"aggs": {
    "topHits_agg": {
        "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{
                "fooField": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }],
            size: 1
        }
    }
}
```

However, the performance is not good. Is there any way to make this better?

Comment: are you looking to get largest value of `fooField` for all `fooId` or specific `fooId`? I asked this question because you have specified **given fooid** in your question and you query is getting **all fooId**

Comment: My bad! It's about a specific `fooId`, I made a mistake while copying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you do not need `aggregation`, you could `sort` on `fooField` directly like this

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "fooId": "your_specific_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "fooField": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to do some serious benchmarking in my case, but sounds like it could be it, I have no idea why I ignored searches. Thanks!